# One click unsubscribe

Tags: marketing-cloud

What is one click unsubscribe? Where is the one click unsubscribe variable? 
Already implement the link of Profile Center with the variable('%%profile_center_url%%') but I want to implement the unsubscribe link in our mail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

%%unsub_center_url%%

The unsubscribe process is broken into two parts.

1. List level unsubscribe: The subscriber clicks the link in the email. The subscriber is unsubscribed from the list, group, or publication list. The subscriber is also brought to a webpage.
2. Master unsubscribe: The subscriber clicks Unsubscribe From All button on the webpage. The subscriber is now unsubscribed at the All Subscribers level (all lists, groups, and publication lists.)

Full documentation: https://help.exacttarget.com/en-GB/documentation/exacttarget/system_guides/unsubscribes/

Few notes:

1. If the subscriber unsubs from a group at the list level, they are only unsubscribed from the group, not the list that created it.
2. By default list level unsubscribes are also mast unsubscribes if the send is to a data extension. A publication list needs to be made and used for list level unsubscribes to a DE send.

Comment: There is also a Business Unit level unsubscribe. You can see it using this data view: _BusinessUnitUnsubscribes